# javascript window.history API on first page load

Tags: javascript, url-routing, html5-history

I am trying to implement a javascript router with window.history API. I've been using ui-router for a long time but I want to create my own router for my smaller apps. Everything looks fine until meeting a problem like this: I am serving my page at localhost:8080/index.html. I am routing in the page with history API related properties. When I click to a route, I lose the index.html part. For example url becomes localhost:8080/home. When I directly try to go to that state, as you expect I get 404 error naturally. How can force to route over index.html to that state?

Comment: Can you share some code of your router? For example the part that is not working as expected?

Comment: I can give [link](http://html5demos.com/history) as the example. I found it when I was searching for the solution and best practises. The same thing happening in here, too.

Comment: problem is; after you route to a few states, when you refresh the browser, it tries to send request

Comment: This is how HTML5 history works, it has to be coupled with a URL rewriter on the server, so that every URL is transformed to call index.html behind the scenes. If you don't have access to the server, you should use/develop instead a classic router with hashbang : `index.html#/my/route`, or do not use javascript routing and simply rely on the server folders architecture to organize html files

Comment: I was avoiding using the hash but there is no way without it I guess. thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 history (`pushState`, etc) works by rewriting the URL on the client side. Hence it needs the server to also be able to rewrite the URL, and load the same `index.html` file whatever the URL.

Without this server rewrite, the two possible options are :

- Use a hashbang JavaScript router based on URL like `/idex.html#!/current/path`
- Do not use JavaScript for routing, and just rely on server directory structure to serve different file for each endpoint

Comment: I was just challenging my self in order to create a ui-router like angular's, crossroads.js or history.js. I decided to use hashbang and looks good :)

Comment: Cool ! Can you validate my answer if it suits you ? Thanks !